# Javascript/jQuery Multi filtered gallery and arrays comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, filter, gallery

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate questions, but I've spent over 8hrs trying to figure out how to implement this, but it seems I haven't succeded so far.

I've got a photo gallery, each foto contains multiple tags. If multiple tags are active, it needs to show only items that include all the selected tags.

```
<ul class="tags-list container">
    <li class="tag toate"><a href="#" data-tag-slug="toate">Toate</a></li>
    <li class="tag"><a href="#" data-tag-slug="tag-1">Tag 3</a></li>
    <li class="tag"><a href="#" data-tag-slug="tag-2">Tag 2</a></li>
    <li class="tag"><a href="#" data-tag-slug="tag-3">Tag 4</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
    <div id="grid-item-0" class="grid-item " data-tag=" tag-1 tag-3 tag-7"></div>
    <div id="grid-item-1" class="grid-item " data-tag=" tag-2 tag-1"></div>
    <div id="grid-item-2" class="grid-item big" data-tag=" tag-3"></div>
    <div id="grid-item-3" class="grid-item " data-tag=" tag-4 tag-2 tag-1"></div>
</div>
```

and JS:

```
function Gallery() {
    this.tag = $('.tags-list .tag');
    this.gridItem = $('.grid .grid-item');
    this.activeTags = ['toate'];
    this.itemsList = [];
    this.activeItems = [];
    this.init();
}

Gallery.prototype.init = function () {
    this.masonry();
    this.itemsListGen();
};

Gallery.prototype.itemsListGen = function () {
    var _this = this;

    $(this.gridItem).each(function () {

        var tags = $(this).attr('data-tag');
        tags = tags.trim();

        // creates an array of objects with every item's id and tags
        _this.itemsList.push({
            'id': $(this).attr('id'),
            'tags': tags.split(' ')
        });
    });

};

Gallery.prototype.masonry = function () {
    $('.grid').masonry({
        // options
        columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        percentPosition: true

    });
};

Gallery.prototype.tagClick = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // currentTag has the clicked tag
    var currentTag = $(e.currentTarget).attr('data-tag-slug');
    $(e.currentTarget).toggleClass('active');

    if ($(e.currentTarget).attr('data-tag-slug') === 'toate') {
        this.toateClick();
    } else {

        // refresh current filters          
this.refreshTags(currentTag);

        // return validated items based on filters
        this.returnValidItems();

        // refresh the layout with the current items
        this.refreshMasonry();
    }
};

Gallery.prototype.refreshTags = function (e) {
    // checks if the current tag is already active
    // if it's active, it removes it and checks if there is any other active tag or should trigger 'toate'
    // if it's not active, it adds it to the activeTags and removes 'toate'

    if (this.activeTags.includes(e)) {
        this.activeTags.splice(this.activeTags.indexOf(e), 1);
        if (this.activeTags.length < 1) {
            this.showAll();
        }

    } else {
        this.activeTags.push(e);

        if (this.activeTags.includes('toate')) {
            this.removeToate();
        }
    }

};

Gallery.prototype.returnValidItems = function () {

    for (var i = 0; i < this.itemsList.length; i++) {
        var itemTags = this.itemsList[i].tags;

        for (var j = 0; j < this.activeTags.length; j++) {
            if (itemTags.includes(this.activeTags[j])) {
                this.activeItems.push(this.itemsList[i].id);
            } else {
                this.activeItems.splice(this.activeItems.indexOf(this.itemsList[i].id), 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }


};

Gallery.prototype.refreshMasonry = function () {
    $('.grid-item').hide();

    for (var i = 0; i < this.activeItems.length; i++) {
        $('#' + this.activeItems[i]).show();
    }

    $('.grid').masonry();
};

Gallery.prototype.showAll = function () {
    console.log('show all');
    this.activeTags = ['toate'];
    this.activeItems = [];
    $('.grid-item').show();
    $('.tags-list').find('.toate a').addClass('active');
    $('.grid').masonry();
};

Gallery.prototype.toateClick = function (e) {
    console.log('toate click');
    $('.tags-list').find('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('.tags-list .toate a').addClass('active');
    this.showAll();
};

Gallery.prototype.removeToate = function () {
    $('.tags-list li.toate > a').removeClass('active');
    this.activeTags.splice(this.activeTags.indexOf('toate'), 1);
};
```

I am not capable of doing it. Please help? :)
Besides of helping me with the problem, any feedback regarding my code is welcomed.